# Comparing double values

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a double whose value i get dynamically and the value is 0.94289988675 and also i get a another double whose value is 0.94289988777 .I just need to compare the two values. But it says they are not same. How can i compare till first four digits of those values.

**Code**:

```
for (z = 0; z < something.Count(); z++)
{
    if (largest == Math.Round(0.94289988675 [z],4))
    {
        //proceed
    }
}
```

largest = 0.94289988675 
0.94289988675[z] comes 0.94289988777. z is.

It does not go in the loop. Please help me out.

Comment: Your syntax for [Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx) is wrong.

Comment: what is something ? Are you finding the largest number in an array ?

Comment: Depending on what `0.94289988675` is maybe you should use Decimal?

Comment: How about if you multiply both numbers by 10000, take the integer value, and compare the integer values?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can i compare till first four bits

I assume you mean 4 digits, not 4 bits.

Just take the Absolute value of the difference:

```
if (Math.Abs(largest - 0.94289988675) < 0.0001) 
{
    //proceed
}
```

Equality is a pretty difficult concept with floating point types, never use the simple `==`

Comment: Perhaps someone should explain of how it works? Please, not me! =D

Comment: @Sinatr - its a fairly simple line of code, what is there to explain ?

Comment: Nothing since last edit (`threshold` has gone and that `==` part). When instead of comparing you offer a solution with different idea - peoples might need to have this idea explained.

Answer (score 7):

You never test floating point values for equality. Ever. In any programming language. The most common way to handle this is to subtract one from the other and compare this difference to a small number commonly called Epsilon. In your case 0.001 for the first four digits might be appropriate. If the difference of both numbers is smaller than your Epsilon value, they are considered equal.

```
double x = ?;
double y = ?;
double epsilon = 0.001;

var difference = Math.Abs(x - y);

var isEqual = difference < espilon;
```

Please note that you should **not** use the constant `Double.Epsilon` for this. That's just bad naming, it's for something completely unrelated.

Comment: `double.Epsilon` is very much related but should indeed not be used here.

Comment: great solution adding double.Epsilon. Thanks!