# Equality on float numbers input by user

Tags: algorithm, floating-point, equality

it's possible that the title of this question is not accurate. currently I'm using [somethig similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15431734/comparing-double-values) to check if two float values are "equals"

```
public boolean equality(float a, float b) {
    return a == b || (Math.abs(a - b) < EPSILON);
}
```

the problem arises when I need check the result of something like **10/3** if the user inputs something like 3.3 it's a valid answer. how to adjust the function to this situation

Comment: Currently, the `a == b` test is redundant.

Comment: @displayName consider infinity

Answer (score 1):

You could add a tolerance per equality check and remove direct equality since it is dependent on the other check and is not reliable.

```
public boolean equality(float a, float b, int numberOfImportantDigits) {
    float tolerance=1.0/pow(10.0,numberOfImportantDigits-1);

    return Math.abs(a - b) < tolerance;
}
```

then

```
equality(10.0f/3.0f, 3.3f, 2)
```

should give 0.03333 < 0.1 which is true.

```
equality(1.0f, 1.0000001f, 2)
```

also should give 0.0000002 < 0.1 so true.

```
equality(2.0f, 2.09f, 2)
```

also gives true.

```
equality(2.00f, 2.10f, 2)
```

may or may not depending on if 2.1 is 2.099999999 in machine or not.

Comment: Yes but how to calculate the value of tolerance, right now I'm using it (it's called epsilon)

Comment: Then you need to specify which digit is important for you.

Comment: I want maximum 2 digits

Comment: Currently I have a test where equality(4f, 4.01f, 2) must be false but I got true

Comment: Why must be false? 0.01 always less than 0.1 so they are equal for all cases of second digit.

Comment: that's the problem the important digits are max 2 but sometimes I need ignore complete or only use one

Answer (score 1):

The logartithm of the input gives you the number of digits in the input (base 10 for decimal). Use exponentation to adjust your epsilon accordingly.

**Edit**: Code Example:

```
static final float EPSILON = 0.01f;

public static boolean equality(float a, float b) {
  if (a == b) {
    return true;
  }
  double digits = Math.log10(Math.max(Math.abs(a), Math.abs(b)));
  double scaledEpsilon = EPSILON * Math.pow(10, digits));
  return Math.abs(a - b) < scaledEpsilon;
}
```

Returns true for (10/3, 3.3) and (100/3, 33) but false for (10/3, 3) and (100/3, 30).

Comment: could you please add some example of this

Answer (score 1):

Round them both to the same number of digits, then compare the rounded values.